# Can I preserve results from applying slicer and append that to results from applying same slicer with a different selection in Excel?

Tags: excel, slicers

I have two slicers in one Excel sheet.

Slicer 1 Options: A, B
Slicer 2 Options (varies by selected item in slicer 1): say X, Y, Z if A is selected, K, L, M, N if B is selected

I want to be able to apply both slicers (say select A, and Y,Z) save those results somewhere and clear the slicer and reapply (say select B and L, M, N) and have a dynamic table that would have both of these results combined. How can I do this in Excel?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

I'm still very much figuring out how slicers work so don't have much sense of how I can approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use some VBA.

Assuming the two columns which have slicers are named *Column1* and *Column2*, and are part of a table named *Table1*, create a second sheet, named *Sheet2*, with "Column1" and "Column2" typed into cells `A1` and `B1` respectively. Then enter the following formula into cell `A2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",,
    UNIQUE(
        FILTER(Table1[Column1],
            SUBTOTAL(3,
                OFFSET(INDEX(Table1[Column1], 1),
                    SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table1[Column1]), , 0),
                )
            )
        )   
    )
)
```

and copy it to cell `B2`, amending all instances of "Column1" in the formula to "Column2".

Then create the following macro:

```
Sub SaveSlicerValues()

Dim LRow As Long, PasteRng As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set PasteRng = .Cells(LRow + 1, 1)
    With .Cells(LRow, 1).Resize(, 2)
        .Copy PasteRng
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

You can now add a shape to the sheet with your table/slicers, assign it this macro, and click it every time you wish to record the current slicer choices.